# Use an object (Label) as a template for others in C# / Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some settings that I want to apply to almost all my `Labels`, so my idea is make a `templateLabel` with my "default properties" and then copy it to my other labels as I create them.

The first that I though was to create a Class that inherits from `Xamarin.Forms.Label` where I define my default properties and then make my Labels with it instead of `new Label()`. But I have a doubt about it, it will be correct(best? only? possible?) way to do it? or exist something like.

```
 var myDefaultPropierties = {Text : "Something", VerticalOptions: LayoutOptions.Center};
 Label myFirstLabel = new Label(myDefaultPropierties);
 Label mySecondLabel = new Label(myDefaultPropierties);
```

Comment: I think what you want is a Style. Look them up. I found some info here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/introduction/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a subclass of `Label` will work, but using a Style, and applying the style to your `Label` is cleaner.

Here's a Style example, in XAML. You can achieve the same result in code, but Styles are mainly meant to be used from XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Something" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
     </ResourceDictionary>
<ContentPage.Resources>

...

<Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" />
```

You'll find more info at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/introduction/

Comment: Have you any luck applying an implicit style to app.xaml?

Comment: @JStevens it works. If it doesn't for you, please report that using the bug tracker